# Deciphering FTPS conversation

Tags: ftps, enterprisedt

Here is a real life conversation (with IP, Hostname and ports masked) between the product I support and the z/OS based FTPS Server:

Our product uses Java FTP libraries from [EnterpriseDT](http://enterprisedt.com/)

```
---> SYST
215 MVS z/OS 011100 is the operating system for Connect:
---> PORT 111,111,111,111,11,111
200 PORT command successful.
---> LIST
150 Opening data connection.
Validating the server certificate when connecting to 'ftp.abc.com'.
Successfully validated the SSL server certificate when connecting to 'ftp.abc.com'
226 List complete. Closing data connection. 1 batches listed.
No input files found on server.
```

I don't understand the last two lines of the conversation. Why do I only receive a list and not the actual file?

Comment: Why would you receive a file if you requested a list of files? Study the FTP specification (RFC 959) for details.

Comment: Sorry, to elaborate, the server says "1 batches listed." But immediately says: "No input files found on server."

Comment: The text in the second line doesn't make sense at all - it should not be there. Check if it's added by the server or the client. Probably contact EnterpriseDT support, they should know better.